# Concatenate strings found by re.findall in Python

Tags: python

Scraping data from a website with a search bar.

I'm using the search with python and then filtering the results for `"Words Like These"`:

```
tabOne = re.findall(r"[A-Z][a-z]*", str(initialFilter))
```

The problem is that the data that I'm trying to get is occasionally multiple words such as 'Item Number One' but the re.findall shows that as `'Item' 'Number' 'One'`.

I want to retain the original form of the data as one phrase of words, but I'm not sure how to tell python to group them together.

The phrases of the **[A-Z][a-z]** words are always isolated from each other on the page, so I was wondering if it might be possible to check if the characters next to those words are `[A-Z][a-z]` as well and if true, group them together.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Two different ways:

1. Change your regex to search for multiple words
2. Join regex results back into string

For (1), you can try something like:

```
tabOne = re.findall(r"((?:[A-Z][a-z]*\s?)+)", str(initialFilter))
```

For (2), you can do something like:

```
tabOne = re.findall(r"[A-Z][a-z]*", str(initialFilter))
results = ' '.join(tabOne)
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't test my regex before I posted.  I'll fix in a second.